# I'm encountering Pyspark Error: Column is not iterable

Tags: python, pyspark

When I try to run follwing code in spark I get the error:

Here is traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-4bfff78eeaad> in <module>()
  1 feature_text='lepton pT, lepton eta, lepton phi, missing energy 
magnitude, missing energy phi, jet 1 pt, jet 1 eta, jet 1 phi, jet 1 b-tag, 
jet 2 pt, jet 2 eta, jet 2 phi, jet 2 b-tag, jet 3 pt, jet 3 eta, jet 3 phi, 
jet 3 b-tag, jet 4 pt, jet 4 eta, jet 4 phi, jet 4 b-tag, m_jj, m_jjj, m_lv, 
m_jlv, m_bb, m_wbb, m_wwbb'
----> 2 features=[strip(a) for a in split(feature_text,',')]

/opt/ibm/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in __iter__(self)
342 
343     def __iter__(self):
--> 344         raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
345 
346     # string methods

TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

code:

```
feature_text='lepton pT, lepton eta, lepton phi, missing energy magnitude, missing energy phi, jet 1pt, jet 1 eta, jet 1 phi, jet 1 b-tag, jet 2 pt, jet 2 eta, jet 2 phi, jet 2 b-tag, jet 3 pt, jet 3 eta, jet 3 phi, jet 3 b-tag, jet 4 pt, jet 4 eta, jet 4 phi, jet 4 b-tag, m_jj, m_jjj, m_lv, m_jlv, m_bb, m_wbb, m_wwbb'

features=[strip(a) for a in split(feature_text,',')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [`pyspark.sql.functions.split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) function, when you're really looking for the string [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

Using the latter, you could generate a list of feature names, without requiring a list comprehension, from your string using:

```
features = feature_text.split(", ")
```

Both `strip` and `split` are methods of `str`, rather than functions, so are called using `my_string.strip(" ")` and `my_string.split(",")`.